# Time complexity of Recursive method

Tags: time-complexity

I am learning time complexity and stumbled upon a method like this:

```
double F(int n)
    {
        if (n <= 1)
            return 4;
        return F(n - 3) + 5 * F(n - 4) + 10 * F(n / 5) + 4 * n;
    }
```

I know the first two lines are just for example like 2*c, where c is a constant, what about the last line? What will be complexity of the whole method?
`F(n) = 2 * c + F(n - 3) + 5 * F(n - 4) + 10 * F(n / 5) + 4 * n =` ?

And also method like:

```
            if (n <= 1)
                return 4;
            if (values[n] != 0)
                return values[n];
            values[n] = F(n - 3) + 5 * F(n - 4) + 10 * F(n / 5) + 4 * n;
            return values[n];
```

How could I count second one? First four lines 4 * c?